# Best practice to handle file permission in git with Jenkins

Tags: linux, git, jenkins, permissions

I have created two scripts in git hook for *pre-commit* to save the Linux permissions for all files in a permission file and *post-checkout* to restore the permissions using the permission file. This is working fine if I do a git clone/checkout/commit manually.

However, when I configure the Jenkins to checkout the project, it will run the following command:

> git checkout -f

This uses *-f* option and attempts to throw away local changes with unlink. This will throw the permission denied error for my project as the Jenkins account have no permission to remove some files (e.g. permission file contains an entry for a file which has root owner). What is the best way to use Jenkins to build my project but preserve permissions for the files in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the best way is not to change permissions of root-owned files. Add excliding of this kind of files in your hooks.

But if you really need it, you may use `sudo` without password for Jenkins account. UPD: Change `chmod` to `sudo chmod` in your hook scripts and add string like `jenkins    localhost = NOPASSWD: /bin/chmod` in /etc/sudoers

Comment: My project contains files for different users (root and other users) so I really need it. How can I configure Jenkins to run `sudo`?

Comment: Change `chmod` to `sudo chmod` in your hook scripts and add string like `jenkins    localhost = NOPASSWD: /bin/chmod` in /etc/sudoers

Comment: Yes I have done that in post-checkout to modify the file permission as root using `sudo chmod`. The issue is when Jenkins perform git checkout -f it attempts to remove file but failed.

Comment: Any idea how should I address the problem? After applying the permission using `sudo chmod`, git checkout -f is unable to remove some files